# Add new Directory with Poco::zip always give Exception

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I'm building a Compress/Decompress functions and currently, I only able to compress 1 single file into a zip file. Each time I add a new Directory or add Recursively a Directory it always give me Exception.

Here is my `ZipFile` function:

```
Poco::DateTime(Timestamp);
        set <string> extensionsSet;
        std::ofstream fos(target, ios::binary);
        Poco::Zip::Compress c(fos, true);

    for (int i = 0; i < extensions.Size(); i++) {
        string ext = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<String>(extensions.operator[](i))->GetPrimitive();
        extensionsSet.insert(ext);
    }
    c.setStoreExtensions(extensionsSet);//set extensions List 



    Poco::File aFile(source);

    if (aFile.exists())
    {
        Poco::Path p(aFile.path());
        if (aFile.isDirectory())
        {
            Poco::Path sourceDir(source);
            Poco::Path targetDir(target);
            c.addDirectory(targetDir, Poco::DateTime(Timestamp));// give exception
            targetDir.makeDirectory();
            c.addRecursive(sourceDir);
        }
        else if (aFile.isFile())
        {
            c.addFile(p, p.getFileName());
        }
    }
    else {
        _log.EndMethod();
        throw new FileNotFoundException("File Not Found");
    }


    c.close(); // MUST be done to finalize the Zip file
    fos.close();
```

Here is where my exception, the underneath block of code is within addDirectory methods of Poco:

```
if (!ZipCommon::isValidPath(fileStr))
        throw ZipException("Illegal entry name " + fileStr + " containing parent directory reference");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a member in "Poco::Path" called "absolute".
You can set absolute to false by constructor

otherwise the ZipException is thrown because this function returns "false":

```
bool ZipCommon::isValidPath(const std::string& path)
{
try
{
    if (Path(path, Path::PATH_UNIX).isAbsolute() || Path(path, Path::PATH_WINDOWS).isAbsolute())
        return false;
}
...
}
```

Here is a example:

```
std::ofstream fos(target, ios::binary);
Poco::Zip::Compress compress(fos, true);
std::vector<std::string> dirs; // parent dirs in zip file
Poco::Path myPath(false); // set path to non-absolute

// add parent directories
for (auto& dir : dirs)
{
  myPath.pushDirectory(dir);
}

//add file
myPath.setFileName("FileName.txt");

//add file to archive
compress.addFile(theFile, relativePath);

//close archive and get zipArchiveObject
ZipArchive zipArchive(compress.close());
```